# Assistance needed to create JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

As I am new to JSON schema creation, I have learnt the basics of JSON schema and now I am trying to create JSON schema for the below mentioned set of data,

```
{
  "Result": [
    {
      "ResourceName": "Appointment",
      "Sequence": "1",
      "Data": {
        "AppointmentID": "A1234",
        "PatientName": "Test Patient",
        "ClinicName": "Test Clinic"
      }
    },
    {
      "ResourceName": "EpisodeofCare",
      "Sequence": "2",
      "Data": {
        "EpisodeID": "EP1234",
        "LocationId": "L1234",
        "AppointmentId": "A1234",
        "TransactionStatus": "2",
        "OPNumber": "OP523367"
      }
    },
    {
      "ResourceName": "Encounter",
      "Sequence": "3",
      "Data": {
        "EncounterID": "E1234",
        "PatientID": "P1234"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Can anybody please help me to create JSON schema for this kind of data set.

Thanks in advance for helping me out on this.

Below is the JSON schema i have drafted

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "ResultType": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "ResourceName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Sequence": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Data": {
          "type": "object",
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Appointment"
            },
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/EpisodeofCare"
            },
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Encounter"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "Appointment": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "AppointmentID": {
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "PatientName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "ClinicName": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "EpisodeofCare": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "EpisodeID": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "LocationId": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "AppointmentId": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "TransactionStatus": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "OPNumber": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "Encounter": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "EncounterID": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "PatientID": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Result": {
      "type": "array",
      "$ref": "#/definitions/ResultType"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please give a verbose explanation of the schema you want to create, be as specific as it can get. An example is not sufficient in that regard. Then share your progress so far and communicate the tools you are using (which schema version, which validator).

Comment: I have included the JSON schema that i have created with my knowledge. Please have a look on this and let me know your views and suggestions on this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Throw it in a schema validator like [this one](https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/).
You will see errors in your schemas definition and in validation.

First of all check that your schema is valid json (the validator might help):

```
[
  {
    {"$ref": "#/definitions/Appointment"}     <- unnecessary and invalid braces
  },
  {
    {"$ref": "#/definitions/EpisodeofCare"}   <- unnecessary and invalid braces
  },
  {
    {"$ref": "#/definitions/Encounter"}       <- unnecessary and invalid braces
  }
]
```

Within the `Result` property you want each item of the array. You should use the `item` property instead of `ref`. As taken from the [specification](https://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.4.1):

> The value of "items" MUST be either a valid JSON Schema or an array of valid JSON Schemas.
>   [...]
>   If "items" is a schema, validation succeeds if all elements in the array successfully validate against that schema.

Thus you should use

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Result": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/ResultType"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since the schema should be as specific as possible you should constraint the content of the `ResourceName` properties to the actual data layout.

Use the `const` property to define a constant value for the `ResourceName` for each type of Resource. Take for example the `Appointment` type, which would change to:

```
"Appointment": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "ResourceName": {
      "const": "Appointment"
    },
    "Data": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "AppointmentID": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "PatientName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "ClinicName": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I also changed the type of `AppointmentID` to string.

Then your `ResultType` needs to be adjusted. Before you used `anyOf` to validate the data, now you need it to validate the complete object while still maintaining the overall structure:

```
"ResultType": {
  "allOf": [
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "ResourceName": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Sequence": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "Data": true
      }
    },
    {
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Appointment"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/EpisodeofCare"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Encounter"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The `allOf` propertiy implies a `and` condition. The overall structure (the object) does not care what value `ResourceName` has or how `Data` is structured. The specific *implementations* (the `anyOf` part) take care of that.

Some final improvements. Use the `required` property to define the names of properties that must exist in your JSON file. Also add `"additionalProperties": false` to ensure that only the specified properties are used. And finally constraint your sequence values to be string representations of positive intergers by adding `"pattern": "[1-9]\\d*"`.

Final result:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "ResultType": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "required": [
            "ResourceName",
            "Sequence",
            "Data"
          ],
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "properties": {
            "ResourceName": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "Sequence": {
              "type": "string",
              "pattern": "[1-9]\\d*"
            },
            "Data": true
          }
        },
        {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Appointment"
            },
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/EpisodeofCare"
            },
            {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/Encounter"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "Appointment": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "ResourceName": {
          "const": "Appointment"
        },
        "Data": {
          "type": "object",
          "required": [
            "AppointmentID",
            "PatientName",
            "ClinicName"
          ],
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "properties": {
            "AppointmentID": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "PatientName": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "ClinicName": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "EpisodeofCare": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "ResourceName": {
          "const": "EpisodeofCare"
        },
        "Data": {
          "type": "object",
          "required": [
            "EpisodeID",
            "LocationId",
            "AppointmentId",
            "TransactionStatus",
            "OPNumber"
          ],
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "properties": {
            "EpisodeID": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "LocationId": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "AppointmentId": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "TransactionStatus": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "OPNumber": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Encounter": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "ResourceName": {
          "const": "Encounter"
        },
        "Data": {
          "type": "object",
          "required": [
            "EncounterID",
            "PatientID"
          ],
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "properties": {
            "EncounterID": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "PatientID": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "Result"
  ],
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "Result": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/ResultType"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create json schema by online tools which generates json schema from the json 
like: https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-json-to-schema-converter , it also checks if json is valid or not.

Json Schema that you need:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Result": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "ResourceName": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "Sequence": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "Data": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "AppointmentID": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "PatientName": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "ClinicName": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "AppointmentID",
                "PatientName",
                "ClinicName"
              ]
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "ResourceName",
            "Sequence",
            "Data"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "ResourceName": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "Sequence": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "Data": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "EpisodeID": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "LocationId": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "AppointmentId": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "TransactionStatus": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "OPNumber": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "EpisodeID",
                "LocationId",
                "AppointmentId",
                "TransactionStatus",
                "OPNumber"
              ]
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "ResourceName",
            "Sequence",
            "Data"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "ResourceName": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "Sequence": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "Data": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "EncounterID": {
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "PatientID": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "EncounterID",
                "PatientID"
              ]
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "ResourceName",
            "Sequence",
            "Data"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "Result"
  ]
}
```